# How to delete files matching pattern within a directory in PHP?

Tags: php

I have created a PHP script to generate CSV files. I want to keep only the latest file which the script creates. How can I delete all older `*.csv` files in a directory using PHP?

Answer (score 12):

```
// Get a list of all CSV files in your folder.
$csv = glob("*.csv");

// Sort them by modification date.
usort($csv, function($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); });

// Remove the newest from your list.
array_pop($csv);

// Delete all the rest.
array_map('unlink', $csv);
```

If your CSV extension may be any case, swap `csv` with `[cC][sS][vV]`. This is a glob pattern.

Comment: Are you sure it will remove files in the same directory where my script is?

Comment: @user1667374 Just set the path correctly when you initially glob the files.

Comment: @user1667374 `glob("your/path/to/files/*.csv")`

Comment: It is giving some syntax error here

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

    $csv = glob("/home/paesana/public_html/store/secure/mas/*.csv");

    usort($csv, function($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); });

    array_map('unlink', $csv);

Comment: @user1667374 You're using < PHP 5.3. Just use a named function reference instead of the anonymous function. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)